# GIS: need to add data to a shape file

Tags: gis, postgis, geoserver

I tried posting this question earlier but was unsuccessful so I'm trying again

I imported a shape (set of points) file into postgres and have a table (hist_info) with additional data also in postgres.  I tried creating a VIEW with data that I need from each files but for a reason I can't figure out as to why my GIS layer (created in geoserver) is blank.  A SELECT * FROM new_view shows there is data in the table created by the VIEW....

So my questions are
1. What data must I include in the VIEW in order for the newly created VIEW will display as points and show the added data when a point is clicked on?

2. What is the best way to combine the two files so that I can display the data from the hist_info table when someone click on one of the points on the map displayed in their browse?

Thanks for the help!!

Regards
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert a record in the geometry_columns table or GeoServer won't read your view's geometry. Have a look at this:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/postgis.html#publishing-a-postgis-view

Comment: Thanks for replying... I'll check out the link and the geoserver forums...
Regards
Chris